LOD algorithm meshlet-based (Nanite style)
I have to implement a LOD algorithm meshlet-based, but I'm wondering about the best approach to use. I would like to use the Task Shader (the new shader stage of the mesh shading pipeline) to apply a per-meshlet simplification based on the meshlet's distance. The doubt that I have is if it is possible to do a per-meshlet simplification within a Task Shader.  I can apply, for example, the edge collapse algorith within the Task Shader ? In this way I will be able to apply a dynamic LOD to my mesh within the GPU. Another possible approach is to use the Nanite's approach. In this case I have to construct a DAG and create different LODs. I think, but maybe I'm wrong, that the Task Shader approach is faster. Any suggestions?
Many thanks
